# Как проверить наличие записей одной пачкой?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Мне необходимо проверить существование Id в БД. Сейчас я проверяю по одной записи, что не очень эффективно

```
    public override long Ask(CountVkInfoById criterion)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(1) 
                       FROM vkinfo
                       WHERE
                           Id = @Id";

        return Connection.ExecuteScalar<long>(sql, new
        {
            Id = criterion.Id
        });
    }
```

Вызывается данный код следующим образом

```
    public IEnumerable<VkDocumentWrapper> GetNotProcessed(IEnumerable<VkDocumentWrapper> inputs)
    {
        var inputsToArray = inputs.ToArray();

        return inputsToArray.Where(x => _queryBuilder.For<long>()
            .With(new CountVkInfoById(x.Document.Id)) == 0);
    }
```

В метод GetNotProcessed поступает коллекция записей, мне нужно из это коллекции получить новую коллекцию, элементов, которых нет в БД -- это проверяется по Id

Comment: Не вижу, где у вас используется метод 'Ask' в 'GetNotProcessed'.

Решением может быть выборка **ID** с таблицы **vkinfo** по условию **IN**,
с последующим сравнением с полным списком IDшек. (например, через LINQ Except(...))

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вы `ToArray()` делаете? Можно же просто `inputs.Where(...)`. Будет минус одна лишняя операция.

Comment: @aepot, на одном из курсов говорили, то если использовать просто IEnumerable, то коллекция будет ленивая. Возможно, я не так посыл понял или несу херню)

Comment: Все верно, ленивая, а что в этом плохого? Преобразование в массив делает копию этой коллекции полным перебором, в вашем случае - просто двойная работа. Копию коллекции имеет смысл делать там, где требуется ее изменять в отрыве от исходной, либо изменять исходную в отрыве от перечисляемой. Другими словами, причины для создания копии обычно весьма очевидные. Просто понятие "ленивая" - это не повод ни для чего, а скорее наоборот способ сэконоить ресурсы.

Comment: @FallDimka, зависит от того, что в IEnumerable лежит под капотом. Там может быть и List. Но какая разница "ленивая" она или нет? Вы прямо здесь получаете результат и используете его один раз.

Comment: @aepot не думаю что тут коллекция имет десятки тисяч елементов, так что без разницы что тут двойной перебор) Основная опастность "ленивых" коллекций если они тяжело вычисляемы (например, сложная логика с yield вызовами) или это квери (IQueryable<>). Тут небольшой массив или List скорее всего)

Comment: @Sergey верно, но даже в этом случае копировать коллекцию для однократного прохода смысла нет.